# How do I read these attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, attack

Attack: Ranged 10 (one creature); +9 vs. Fortitude

Attack: Melee 2 (one creature); +9 vs. AC

Attack: Ranged 5/10 (one creature); +6

Can anybody break these down for me?

Comment: Hey @John - we kinda frown on asking questions that are basic "in the book" questions here.  I'm glad ObliviousSage helped you out but before flooding the site with too many questions you may want to get more comfortable with the game rules as printed and then ask. It's why your questions aren't getting many upvotes, read the hover-over on the vote up to see the criteria - "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear."

Answer (score 5):

**Attack:** This ability attacks people.

**Ranged 10 (one creature):** Pick one creature within 10 squares of you. That's who you're attacking. It's a ranged attack, so it provokes opportunity attacks from any enemies adjacent to you.

**+9 vs Fortitude:** Roll a d20 and add 9 to the result. If the number you got is equal to or greater than the target's Fortitude defense, you hit. If it's less than their Fortitude defense, you missed.

**Melee 2 (one creature):** Pick one creature within 2 squares of you. That's who you're attacking. Melee attacks do *not* provoke opportunity attacks.

**+9 vs AC:** Roll a d20 and add 9 to the result. If the number you got is equal to or greater than the target's AC defense, you hit. If it's less than their AC defense, you missed.

**Ranged 5/10 (one creature):** Pick a creature within 10 squares of you. That's who you're attacking. If it's within 5 squares of you, proceed as normal. If it's within 10 squares of you (a valid target), but *not* within 5 squares of you, you take a -2 penalty on the attack roll (the +X vs AC/Fortitude/Reflex/Will roll). Since it's a ranged attack, you provoke attacks of opportunity from any adjacent enemies.

This is moving into *really* basic stuff. Have you read the PHB (or Rules Compendium)? If not, **go do that**. If you're still having problems, you might be better off asking about them in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat), which you appear to have enough rep to speak in.

Comment: PHB or Rules Compendium.

Comment: Yeah, I just needed a super fast answer as I am in need of it now. Thank you for giving me a very good answer :)